# How do I reorder tabs in visual basic? When I hide then show a tab it appears last rather than first

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms, tabs

How do I reorder tabs in visual basic? When I hide then show a tab it appears last rather than first.

Code:

```
Dim tab As TabPage
Dim checktab As Integer = 0
Private Sub HideTabPage(tabPage As TabPage)
    tab = tabPage
    Me.SearchExtras.TabPages.Remove(tabPage)
    checktab = 1
End Sub

Private Sub UnHideTabPage()
    If checktab = 1 Then
        Me.SearchExtras.TabPages.Add(tab)
        checktab = 0
    End If
End Sub
```

Reply Quote

Comment: Use Insert() instead.  Hiding multiple tab pages and getting them inserted back in the right spot, that's a bit trickier.  And won't work in your existing code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [TabPageCollection.Insert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7te5wzay.aspx) instead of Add, and specify the index at which you want the tab to be inserted, so in your case it can look like this:

```
Me.SearchExtras.TabPages.Insert(0, tab)
```